# iOS: What happens between init and loadView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an Objective-C app with a programmatically created view for which I'm seeing strange (to me) behavior. Specifically, there's a long pause (up to 30 seconds) between the end of the init method and the beginning of the loadView method. I'm unable to see anything out of the ordinary when setting breakpoints at both those places, so I'm wondering what the system is doing between the init and the loadView, and whether there's anything I can do to optimize the work being done at that point.

Thanks.

**Edit:** adding some code below (abbreviated for clarity)

The app plays and records video. This view controller reviews a video that's just been recorded but not yet saved / posted.

```
// called from the view controller that pushes this onto the navigation controller stack
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)fileURL
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
      self.localFileURL = fileURL;
      sessionManager = [[sessionManager alloc] initWithURL:fileURL];
    }
    NSLog(@"return self");
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    NSLog(@"begin loadView");
    self.playView = [[PlayView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
    self.view = self.playView;
}
```

The pause occurs between the two logging statements.

Comment: Provide relevant code in your question. Also make sure you aren't creating or showing the view controller on a background thread.

Comment: @rmaddy done, see above. not sure I immediately know how to check the controller isn't being created on a bg thread, but it sounds a good suggestion, so I'll try to figure that out, thanks.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `nitWithURL` and the `loadView` methods and see what thread they are called on.

Comment: indeed @rmaddy, they are both being called on Thread 7

Comment: and yes @rmaddy, after wrapping a dispatch_get_main_queue around the code that instantiates the view, it works like a charm. Happy to credit you if you want to add an answer. In any case, many thanks!

Comment: Does sessionManager do something on the main thread that might be taking a long time? For example some synchronous network calls.

Comment: There is also the NSThread method isMainThread. You can use code like this:     `if (![[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) NSLog(@"Running on background thread!");`